# Using multiple commands in the <init> part of a Powershell for loop

Tags: powershell

I get an error when trying to use multiple commands in the <Init> part of a for loop in Powershell. For example,

```
function Example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [int] $Base,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [int] $Count
    )
    Process {        
        for ( $item = 1, $id = $Base; $item -le $Count; $id++, $item++ ) {
        }
    }
}

Example -Base 1 -Count 2
```

The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) says that <Init> "represents one or more commands" and that <Repeat> "represents one or more commands, separated by commas". The wording is different, so I realize that the syntax may be different.

The error I get is "The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property." with the underscore beneath the 1 in "$item = 1".

Comment: You need to separate the variable assignments using a grouping operator: `($item = 1), ($id = $Base)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the `<init>` component of your [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) either with [`Subexpression operator $(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--):

```bash
for($($item1 = 0; $item2 = 10); $item1 -lt 10 -or $item2 -gt 0; $item1++, $item2--) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        item1 = $item1
        item2 = $item2
    }
}
```

Or, as [Abraham points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965517/using-multiple-commands-in-the-init-part-of-a-powershell-for-loop#comment125453321_70965517), each variable assignment wrapped with parentheses: `($item1 = 0), ($item2 = 10)`.

Following your example function, this should work:

```bash
function Example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $Base,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $Count
    )

    Process {
        for (($item = 1), ($id = $Base); $item -le $Count; $id++, $item++) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                item = $item
                id   = $id
            }
        }
    }
}

Example -Base 4 -Count 10
```

Comment: @mklement0 agreed, even tho it works the docs don't mention it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating; even `$(...)` isn't mentioned in the docs (but is preferable to the awkward (`(...), (...), ...` syntax that is documented), but since whatever is used for the `<init>` part produces _no output_, `$(...)` seems like the more natural fit, given that the sole reason to use `@(...)` would be to guarantee array _output_, which is therefore a moot point here.

Comment: @mklement0 they only show `$(..)` in the examples but yes, not "documented", no wonder why it could be confusing for others new to PS

Comment: Ah, good point - I missed the `$(...)` examples in the docs.